# Quick Volume of Revolution Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant enclosed by the graph of $f(x)=\sqrt(\cos(x))$, the graph of $g(x)=e^x$, and the vertical line $x=\frac {\pi}{2}$, as shown in the figure below. Write, but do not evaluate, an integral expression that gives the area of $R$. "

[image]

I'm a bit confused about how I'd go about finding the area for this specific question. I understand that the volume of revolution would be found by integrating the area formula with the bounds from $0$ to the top of the graph on the y-axis, but I'm a bit confused about what the area formula would look like here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$R = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{x}dx- \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cos(x)}dx,$$

i.e. $R$ is the difference between the area under the highest curve ($e^x$) and the area under the lowest curve ($\sqrt{\cos(x)}$).

Comment: Totally forgot to add in the square root over the $\cos$, I'm assuming the answer would still be the same, just with a square root over the $\cos$?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, since $e^x > \sqrt{\cos(x)}$ for all $x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.